# Play youtube video in full screen using external link in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-javascript-api

Hello is it possible to control the fullscreen option in youtube video embedded in any site using external link ?
I am using iframe to load the youtube url:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hrbKp5N74zE?rel=0"
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now I have a link with id 'showFullScreen'.

Here is Jquery :-

```
$(function(){
  $('a#showFullScreen').live('click',function(){
      /*
       * Full Screen code here
      */

  });
});
```

Comment: I know that it's been asked a long time ago, but I'm curious how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [jQuery plugin](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/) to toggle fullscreen. On `fullscreeneventchange` resize your video to 100% width and height and position it on top (revert on close).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually looking for the youtube option to get the full screen from external button or links.